# StreamCorruptedException with heavy data over ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, corruption, objectinputstream

I have a server-client setup over TCP where the client is sending a number of data sets to the server.  The reading/writing uses ObjectInput/OutputStream.  I don't have any problems under normal conditions, but when the data flow gets heavy, I get a StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code.  The invalid code is different every time.  I open the socket once and call a synchronized method to send data from multiple threads.

Client:

```
socket = new Socket("localhost", sockNum);
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

public synchronized void sendMsg(Message msg){
    try{
        out.writeObject(security.signObject(msg, privKey));
        out.reset();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(sockNum);
Socket client = server.accept();
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

while(threadActive){
    Object line = in.readObject();
    handleObject(line);
}
```

**Update: I added out.reset() after each send, but that didn't help the problem.  I've also added sleep statments in my loop to decrease the data rate.  This gets rid of the error but is not a real solution.**

Edit:  So it's been a little while since I originally asked this, but I'm running into the problem again.  I tried setting up my system so that after every sent message, the thread waits for an "acknowledge" message in return.  If the receiving process has the StreamCorruptedException, it sends back a "resend" rather than an ack.  This seems to be causing more problems than solutions.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Is that method the only place you access `out` or `socket` except when creating them and closing them?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: The sendMsg method is actually contained in another object which keeps track of all of the I/O variables.  This method is called from multiple threads in my process.  The only other method being called in these threads only calls `in.readObject()`, which has a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are writing to the output stream in a multi threaded way i.e. you are writing to it somewhere other than in your example.

BTW: Are you reset()ing the stream regularly to prevent a memory leak?

Comment: Yes, I am calling sendMsg() from multiple threads.  Is this problematic?  Also, I have not been reset()ing the stream regularly.  How/when do I do this so as not to lose information being sent from another thread?

Comment: If you change an object while its being serialized it could corrupt the stream. The Object Stream remembers every object it has ever sent. Using reset() clears this cache at both ends.

Comment: Does this apply for nested objects?  I am sending a SignedObject which contains a Message which contains data which does change at some point.  If this is the case, my increase in data flow may be delaying the transmission long enough for this to have an effect.

Comment: If you have an ArrayList, for example, and you change it while ti is being serialized, it can corrupt the a stream.

Comment: I tried adding an out.reset() after the send (as updated in code), but didn't fix it.